# What exactly was Roswaal's role within Re:Zero?

Tags: re-zero

I have just finished the anime, and althugh given that the show did a really good job at tying up loose ends with the plot, I still do not get Roswaal L Mathers' purpose within the plot. According to my memory, he was/did the following:

> - Head of the mansion and the Mathers Domain
>  - Helped with the fight between Subaru et al. and the *majuu* packs
>  - Sponsored Emilia for the election
>
>  ...But then he wasn't seen within the show afterwards (for the latter section, at least).

Did his character play a bigger role that I overlooked? (Or potentially in a later release of the manga that has not been anime-tized?)

Comment: afaik, he's a powerful magician, but had to go for an inspection in a faraway region of his Domain. The cultists took advantage of this to stage their attack on the village where his mansion is located. This is why he's not shown after the events in the Castle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roswaal has an ulterior motive. It has not been shown in anime yet. As of now, the anime covers only the first three arcs of the light novel. His motive is fully explained in arc 4.

> His goal is to meet Echidna, Witch of Greed. This is why he helps both Emilia and Subaru.

Answer (score 1):

Roswaal is one of the main mastermind in the settings of Re: Zero world.

He is The first Roswaal named Roswaal A Mathers (A = Arthur). He wants to meet his teacher Echidna once again and that's why he has been possessing his successors. Current Roswaal is the 12th generation Roswaal. He brings Emilia to his mansion and assists her to stand as an ruler candidate. He hired Elsa (Crazy Assassin) to steal Emilia's emblem. Though it wasn't revealed why (Maybe I don't know). But it might have something to do with Echidna.

He surely is a madlad